# How do you highlight a row if criteria has been met?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-conditional-formatting

Im using Google Sheets and I am trying to highlight a row Green if the numbers 1,2,3 and 4 are found within the outcome row. The whole row would be highlighted indicating whether or not it was successful.

You can view my work here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12kOGdkq9P78gCojHJGW0xPVNXaTFAbFDZ4JLEX09H0U/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried conditional formatting but I cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added another sheet to your spreadsheet (called "Erik Help"), which offers another alternative (which I've applied to B1:L60):

```
=ArrayFormula(($B1="Outcome")*(RIGHT(JOIN("",SORT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE($C1:$L1)),1,1)),4)="1234"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Also just for fun

```
=arrayformula(($B1="Outcome")*product(countif($C1:$L1,{1,2,3,4})))
```

Comment: Nice, Tom. You've opened my mind to a new tool here, which I love.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=($B1=$B$2)*
 (REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($C1:$L),,9^9)), " 1 |1 | 1"))* 
 (REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($C1:$L),,9^9)), " 2 |2 | 2"))* 
 (REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($C1:$L),,9^9)), " 3 |3 | 3"))* 
 (REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($C1:$L),,9^9)), " 4 |4 | 4"))
```

[image: 0]